# Variável de sessão sempre retorns Null Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Classe Empresa:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public long empresaId { get; set; }
    public string nomeEmpresa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe Seu Login", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string loginEmpresa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a senha do usuário", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]

    public string senhaEmpresa { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Projeto> Projetos{get;set;}
}
```

Action para fazer Login:

```
public ActionResult LoginEmpresa(string x, string y)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //verifica se é válido
    {
        //var v = context.Empresas.Where(a => a.loginEmpresa.Equals(empresa.loginEmpresa) && a.senhaEmpresa.Equals(empresa.senhaEmpresa)).First();


        string login = empresaServico.ObterEmpresaPorLogin(x).ToString();
        string senha = empresaServico.ObterEmpresaPorSenha(y).ToString();

        if ((login != null) && (senha != null))
        {
            //Session["empresaLogadaID"] = .ToString();
            Session["nomeEmpresaLogada"] = login.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("/Projeto/Index");
        }

        else return RedirectToAction("/Projeto/Index");
}
```

View para onde ela redireciona:

```
@{if (Session["nomeEmpresaLogada"] != null)
{
    <h2>Bem-vindo(a),@Session["nomeEmpresaLogada"].</h2>

    <div>
        Relação de projetos

    </div>
```

Comment: Verifique se a sua variável login realmente tem algum valor para ser atribuido na session amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
 <h2>Bem-vindo(a), @Session["nomeEmpresaLogada"].ToString().</h2>
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380363/access-session-variable-in-view

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431708/how-can-i-create-session-inside-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Creio que se a Session retorna Null não vai adiantar o método extensivo ToString()

Comment: A Session ta retornando null

Answer (score 0):

Quando utilizo estou fazendo desta forma:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", variavel);
```

e para ler a `Session`:

```
HttpContext.Session.GetString("Nome")
```

Você já verificou se ele recebe algum valor e após isso que fica `null` ?

Comment: Ela está retornando null

Comment: @NicésioJunior Nesta linha `Session["nomeEmpresaLogada"] = login.ToString();` quando vc coloca um `breakpoint` o `login.ToString()` possui algum valor ?